# Django-Rest-Auth: Require another field at registration

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am managing some userdata using Django. I would like to offer the humans behind that data the possibility to take a look at it by registering and connecting their accounts to the existing data (at once).

I therefore handle them a authentification-token, printed on a sheet of paper, in order to connect their already existing data to their accounts they have to send that token along with their desired username, email, password etc.

My Userdata Model looks like this:

```
class Userdata(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    useraccount = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model())
    auth_token = models.CharField(max_length=12, default="DUMMY", unique=True)
```

Therefore I would like to change the registration process, using djang-rest-auth and allauth to check if there exists a row in the `userdata` table where the `auth_token` equals the provided one at the registration.

If, then I would like to set the `useraccount` field in this row to the newly created account, if not, then I would like to raise an error and stop the registration of the account.

---

I am totally lost at the moment and have no idea where to start. I would really appreaciate any hint into the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @somil I came finally up with the following working but yet dirty solution

```
from rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer
from apps.FOOBAR.models import Userdata

# ...

class TokenRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    pass

    # adding the token field to the default serializer
    token = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    # adding a token validator: check if there is a userdata with this token
    def validate_token(self, token):
        try:
            Userdata.objects.get(auth_token=token)
            return token
        except Patient.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Token seems to be invalid, try again")

    # this method is called at save
    def custom_signup(self, request, user):
        # connect the data with the user
        data = Userdata.objects.get(
            auth_token=self.validated_data.get('token', ''))
        data.useraccount = user
        data.save()
```

And, in the `settings.py`

```
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'apps.api.serializers.TokenRegisterSerializer',
}
```

Comment: The custom_signup method exists in RegisterSerializer specifically to be overridden, so I don't think this is a dirty way to do it at all. I think this is pretty much exactly what you're supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite **validate** method in serializer

I guess you are using https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/
then overwrite the serializer

```
 class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer)
```

which is in 
https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/registration/serializers.py file

Comment: Thank you so far, I will dig a bit deeper there.